# Solve parse error for my app

Tags: android, air

I designed a test app for an android phone in Flash CS5.5 with AIR for Android. I tried it in computer in Adobe Device Central and it is working fine. Now, I want to run it on my android device. I published it as AIR for Android player and got a .apk file. I copied it to my device and ran it. But it showed *Parse Error - There is a problem parsing the package*.

How do i make it run on my Android device?? I am new at making apps and don't know any complicated languages. Can any one help me fix this error easily?? Your help is much appreciated!!

EDITED: I searched a lot but Flash didn't generate any AndroidManifest.xml Can anyone tell me what that is and how to generate it and whether it can help me or not??Thanks in advance

Comment: try to change your packegename..

Comment: No experience with AIR but on plain Android this would be a problem with the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Is there a manifest file you could include in your question?

Comment: In AIR-Android the `AndroidManifest.xml` is usually generated from `yourApp-app.xml` [(The app descriptor file)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff1.html)